# Vauxhall Corsa heating problems

Tags: heater, vauxhall, corsa

I have a Vauxhall Corsa 1.3 CDTI EcoFlex and initially when I bought it the heater resistor we thought was broken as the blower fans would only work on dial 4, we replaced it and it worked for about a week and it only works on 4 again, thats my first problem!

Secondly, this may be related but my heating takes an awfully long time to heat up and if the engine is running but the car is idle it blows cold air after about 10-15 minutes of solid driving it finally slowly heats up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue #1: You probably blew the second resistor. Sometimes it just happens. I'd take it back to the place you bought it from and tell them it was defective.

Issue #2: It sounds as though **your thermostat is stuck open and should be replaced**. If coolant is allowed to flow unchecked through the system, you'll only get cold air through your HVAC until the entire system heats up, then it will only be luke warm to moderately warm, but probably will never get completely hot. You can probably look at your temp gauge in the dash and see that the engine isn't warming up all the way.

Comment: Just checked and my coolant temp is around 36-37c is this normal? I don't really know much about the heating system.

Comment: @Kieron606 - That seems *very low* to me. It should be running about 87-88°C (190°F).

Comment: So what would be the cause of this?

Comment: As I stated in *Issue #2* answer, a stuck thermostat is the most likely cause.